# Swift: adding elements to a dictionary recursively

Tags: swift, swift3

In the code:

```
var exerciseNames: [String] = []
var orientation  : [String] = []
var tags         : [String] = []
var mainData     :[[String]] = [[String]]()

var patientData  : [String:String] = [:]

mainData.append(exerciseNames)
mainData.append(orientation)
mainData.append(tags)
var i = 1
for obj in mainData {
    patientData[i] = [obj(exerciseNames), obj(orientation), obj(tags)]
    i += 1
}
```

Xcode throws an error in the `for` loop, specifically at `patientData[I]`:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'superscript'

I think it has something to do with `i` being an integer, but I do not know how to fix this.

My goal here is to create a new dictionary entry, with index `i`, containing an array of three nested arrays, which themselves have a variable number of elements.

If it is important, all of this is in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: `patientData` is not an array. It is a dictionary with key of type String. Please set it as `patientData["\(i)"] = ....` I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do. But this may work. Otherwise change it to array of arrays.

Comment: That throws `Contextual type 'String' cannot be used with array literal`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107743/swift-3-extend-an-array-of-dictionarystring-any

Comment: Your right hand side is also wrong. It expects a string, but you give it an array. You should rethink your code logic.

Comment: You seem not to know what dictionary is, or what `[String:String]` means.

Comment: I literally found the dictionary ~20 minutes ago. Is there a way that I can organize data in a way that a single element is an array of three nested arrays?

Comment: FYI - nothing about your code suggests the use of recursion. What do you mean by "adding to a dictionary recursively"?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `[[[String]]]`? An array of array of array of strings? you have `exerciseNames` which is `[String]` type. Then you have `[obj(exerciseNames), obj(orientation), obj(tags)]` which I believe is `[[String]]`. And you are adding all these in a for-loop so I guess you expect `[[[String]]]` is that true? Then you should change your `patientData` to that type.

Comment: I mean adding a new reference a variable number of times, @maddy

Comment: @adev I did `var num = 1...3
        var exerciseNames: [String] = []
        var orientation  : [String] = []
        var tags         : [String] = []
        var mainData     :[[String]] = [[String]]()

        var patientData  : [[[String]]] = [[[String]]]()
        
        mainData.append(exerciseNames)
        mainData.append(orientation)
        mainData.append(tags)
       
        for i in num {
            patientData.append([["\(i)"], ["\(mainData)"]])
        }`  would this work as desired?

Comment: If you are changing the type, then you can use your above code `patientData[i] = [obj(exerciseNames), obj(orientation), obj(tags)]` because it is an array now. Not dictionary. BTW I am not sure what is `obj(exerciseNames)`.

Comment: `obj(foo)` is supposed to be a representation of each element in `mainData`. So `obj(exerciseNames)` should be (for now) an empty array found in `mainData`.

Comment: @ColePetersen OK, that's iteration, not recursion.

Answer (score 0):

`patientData` is a dictionary keyed by strings. You cannot subscript such a dictionary with a number.

> a new dictionary entry, with index `i`

No. Dictionaries do not have indexes. They have keys. And your keys are strings. If you wanted an array, you should have used an array. If you wanted a dictionary keyed by Ints, you should have used a dictionary keyed by Ints.

Answer (score 0):

I created a process which works like a charm. Thanks for the help!

```
    var numPatients  = 0...0
    var numExercises = 0...0
    var exerciseNames: [String] = []
    var orientation  : [String] = []
    var tags         : [String] = []
    var mainData     :[[String]] = [[String]]()

    var patientData  : [[String]] = [[String]]()
    exerciseNames.append("test exercise")
    exerciseNames.append("test exercise 2")
      orientation.append("test orientation")
             tags.append("test Tags")

    mainData.append(exerciseNames)
    mainData.append(orientation)
    mainData.append(tags)
    for h in numPatients{
        patientData.append(["\(h)"])
        for i in numExercises {
            patientData.append(["\(i)"])
            for j in 0...2 {
                print("\(h,i,j)")
                print(["\(mainData[j][i])"])
                patientData.append(["\(mainData[j][i])"])
                print(patientData)
            }
        }
    }
```